# perl can't locate module even though it's there

Tags: perl, require

I am trying to boot a catalyst app, but it keeps failing on start up because it says that it can't find the module [HTML::FormHandler::Field::TextArea](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::FormHandler::Field::TextArea) that I use. This is the error it gives me:

```
Can't locate HTML/FormHandler/Field/Textarea.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
/usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/
x86_64-linux-thread-multi 
/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .)
```

However, I've looked in my filesystem and I know for a fact that the module is located at `/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/HTML/FormHandler/Field/TextArea.pm`. And as you can see above `@INC` does include the path to this file. Does anyone know why the script can't find it? Thanks!

Comment: can you please explain why you gave me a down vote?

Comment: probably because the answer was right in front of you in the error message... never trust your eyes; always cut&paste, including files your locating.

Comment: You wrote `use HTML::FormHandler::Field::Textarea` instead of `use HTML::FormHandler::Field::TextArea`. Which would have worked (accidently) on Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Textarea` should be `TextArea` would be my thought.  Including your code would nail it.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks a lot! Sometimes you just need another set of eyes :)

Comment: @srchulo Also it helps that I was sure it was your code, while by not posting it, you indicated that you were sure it was Perl.